# I keep getting a date format error when trying to convert an int into a date

Tags: python, pandas

So I currently have a dataset that has a date column as an int, for example `102809` as `10/28/2009`. So I'm trying to convert this column into an actual date column that would have the correct date format.

I tried this code from another question on stack overflow:

```
curry['Datetime'] = curry['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%m/%d/%Y'))
```

But this line returns this error:`time data '102809' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)`

Comment: `'102809'` does not have slashes.  Why are you trying to use a format string with slashes?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
curry['Datetime'] = curry['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%m%d%y'))
```

I have removed the slashes and change the %Y to lower case -> %y, because it is only two digits year

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your date format is two-digits each for month, day and year, so your format should be `'%m%d%y'` with no slashes.  (A two-digit year is `%y` not `%Y`.) Also, there is no need to use `df.apply()` which is slower.

```
curry['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(curry['Date'], format='%m%d%y')
```

Comment: ah! I posted the same solution. I delete my post